# Why is my HTML POST request form not going through to Express app.post? How do I pass on the number variables to another POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I think I am doing something wrong, or have misinterpreted what I've read online about POST and GET requests. I have a submit form on myNumber.ejs. When I press submit, there is the view of Add.ejs. Add.ejs is supposed to show the number and the number+1 value. But the Add POST request doesn't work, and number+1 shows up as 0. It only works if I put the calculations in the Add GET request.

I have it as method="post", but the method that renders and does the math is GET (shows 0 and 1). I can leave it as POST in myNumber.ejs and GET still works. app.post doesn't do anything, the math for it leaves all the variables to = 0. I am confused on why this is happening, I thought post only leads to app.post.

Comment: Did you installed body-parser to parse your incoming post request?

Comment: @Ifaruki yes I do have body-parser installed! How would I use it in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the form submits, you are canceling the submission and opening a popup instead. The popup is just a normal get request.
To submit the form into the popup, try this:

```
<form class="" onsubmit="centeredPopup('/add','myWindow','700','300','yes');" target="myWindow" action="/add" method="post">
        <p>Count: <%= myNum %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md" name="button">Add</button></p>    
</form>
```

Assuming that the 2nd argument of centeredPopup is the window name, for the POST to work `centeredPopup('/add','this'` and `<form target="this"` need to be the same and you can't have `return false`

Comment: Thank you so much you are amazing!!!!! I am so grateful! It worked! This makes so much sense! I kept googling things and being so frustrated! Do you know how to pass these variables onto another ejs file after I close the popup window with a button? I don't want to lose the values, but I can't seem to access the "changed variables" from each different post request.

Comment: I can help, but please ask in a seperate question.

Comment: Hello again! I asked the question here, if you can help me please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242772/how-to-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-one-form-and-update-var-values